# Allwinner A13 tablet stuck on boot screen

Tags: boot, tablet, clock-speed

Okay, here's the deal- I received a generic Chinese tablet from a friend in early January, and it worked well for about two-and-a-half months. Then, just recently, I discovered rooting and the wonderful things it allowed you to do, and my problem followed shortly after. I decided to download a system-tweak app, which included a CPU control. I was a little wary of overclocking my CPU, having heard it may decrease its life expectancy, but finally I thought "What the heck?" and in a brilliant stroke of genius cranked my 1Ghz processor up to 1.5Ghz, and it promptly froze, forcing me to power it down. When I turned it back on, I discovered that it had been factory reset. I re-installed my apps, including the system-tweak app, and decided not to touch the CPU controls for a while. Soon after, while at my sister's talent show, I discovered I had about 30% battery life, and I was still supposed to record her. So I figured I'd underclock it to save the battery. Unfortunately, as my finger touched the slider, my brother bumped my arm and caused me to lower the CPU frequency to its lowest setting. It became extremely sluggish, almost to the point of being unresponsive, and finally I had to shut it down. When I restarted it, it started to boot but then got stuck on the shimmering Android logo, and now that's all it does. I can't even boot into recovery mode, and unfortunately I had just turned off USB debugging that same day. I would like to know if there's any way to get it working again, and if so, how. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!